# Ошибка: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x

Понимаю возможно для вас мои методы кажутся примитивными, но Питон начал изучать всего 3-4 дня назад

```
a = int(input())
b = list(map(int, input().split()))
q = c = int(input())
w = []
p = 0
while q > 0:
   d= list(map(int, input().split()))
   w.extend(d)
   q -= 1
   print(w)
while c > 0:
    print(a[w[p]:w[p+1]:]) #на этом месте выдает ошибку:'int' object is not subscriptable
    c -= 1
    p += 2
```

Comment: Потому что `a` это целое число. Вы видимо хотели: `print(b[w[p]:w[p+1]:])`, т.к. `b` - это список и у вас все получится)

Comment: Давайте переменным осмысленные имена, намного облегчает поиск ошибки. Например, переменные cnt и list_cars. Логично, что cnt будет int-овой переменной, и срез для нее не работает. А list_ сразу намекает, что это итерируемый объект.

Comment: Спасибо большое, догнал

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас переменная `a` - ссылается на объект `int`, а в строчке с ошибкой вы берете `a` в каком-то срезе. В срезе ж можно только итерируемые объекты брать

Comment: Спасибо большое, догнал

Comment: Вы, кстати, можете отметить ответ как правильный, чтобы он переместился вверх и другие участники сразу видели решение)

Comment: вернулся через 5 лет и отметил ваш ответ правильным))